# How do ways of connecting clauses affect a sentence’s meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction

How should we think about this sentence?

*Source : GMAT VERBAL AND WRITING*

**After awakening from his afternoon nap, Jim walked aimlessly from room to room, *searching* for something to do.**

1. After awakening from his afternoon nap, Jim walked aimlessly from room to room, **who searched** for something to do.
2. After awakening from his afternoon nap, Jim walked aimlessly from room to room **by searching** for something to do.
3. After awakening from his afternoon nap, Jim walked aimlessly from room to room **and searched** for something to do.

Comment: It's (3). Searching wasn't Jim's method of walking (!), he was doing both things at the same time.

Comment: what about '' who '' ?

Comment: See Paul's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The party referred to by the  *who* would be “room to room,” which is clearly nonsensical.

The *by* would mean Jim’s method or means of walking was searching for something to do. Also nonsensical.

This leaves *and*, which, fortunately, works nicely. It conjoins two clauses(the latter of which has its subject elided because it’s the same as the former’s) and makes no claim about a logical relationship between them beyond that the walking and searching happened simultaneously.

Comment: The relative clause usually describes the word closest to it, or the relative pronoun takes the place of the word closest to it. I know this. But not always. So, what about this ?       The volunteers arrived at the clinic ,feeling a little nervous Source : Compact Advanced C1

Comment: Yes, those are the patterns that lead the listener or reader to try out *rom to room* as the subject of *searched*. And that’s not the only problem with sentence 1. There’s only one entity in its universe of discourse that could sensibly be the subject of *search*, only one actor, which is *Jim*. So *who*, which specifies **which** person, has no place here for this additional reason too.

Comment: Actually I think this sentence is like this. this is not a relative clause. what do you think? The volunteers arrived at the clinic  '' by ''feeling a little nervous.

Comment: I understand you to be asking about an utterance, \**The volunteers arrived at the clinic **by** feeling a little nervous*. The asterisk (star) I put in front of it is the way that linguists flag utterances as unacceptable, which that one is. The meaning of *by* in (valid) sentences of the form *NP V **by** X* is that *X* is the means or method of the agent’s (described by the noun phrase *NP*) performing or achieving the verb *V*. And feeling a little nervous, while it might be a **manner** in which to arrive, is not a means or method of arriving.

Comment: Example means or methods include *walking* and *by having their spouses drive them there,* and even such single nouns as *bicycle*.